# Can I own more then one freighter?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I rescued a (second) freighter from attacking pirates. Can I own/acquire a second freighter?

If yes, how can I switch between my two (or more?) freighters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have multiple freighters - only one.  If you try to buy another, it will replace your current one.

Sources:

- [Steam Post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/4/2592234299536217426/)
- [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/928itd/owning_more_than_one_freighter/)
- [Wiki](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Freighter#Upgrading_Freighters)

The Wiki points out:

> When purchasing a new freighter any upgrades/built areas and inventories on the old freighter will be lost without offering an option to transfer from the old freighter.

Comment: Does it make a difference, if I get a second freighter "for free" or I buy another one?

Comment: @PeterCo if you can't buy a second one without it getting rid of the first one, I dont think getting one for free will work either